# How to avoid repetitive code in similar view controllers?

Tags: ios, oop, uiviewcontroller

in iOS, A lot of times my project has similar screens with some differences here and there.
With time a similar screen might come upp which I wont be aware of while I was making the  initial architecture.

So, In such cases what I do is having few enum properties and put in if-else statements do differentiate in the code.

Looks ugly! specially when we implement something in TableView datasource and delegate methods, everywhere there is the same if-else or a switch case.

Now If I make a separate VC then I have to copy paste a lot of same code here and there.
If one of them has a bug then its everywhere and its very difficult to trace.

and Given the deadlines,It becomes very difficult to put common things in parent classes up front because I am not sure whether a similar screen will come or not in future.

So what is a generic approach to  not to fall into this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you have 3 options:

`inheritance` Have a superclass of MySpecialViewController that has methods you find useful to be available and be able *override* in subclasses to add additional functionality for that class.  You mention that you 'don't have time' to do this ahead of time, thats fine, figure out what methods are common and create a superclass after the fact and have your view-controllers be subclasses of it.

`categories` If you don't need to override the shared functionality AND you're running into multiple inheritance issues create categories that contain the helper methods you want to use across your view controllers.

`utility class`  If the methods you're reusing can function in their own class and for some reason the above two options don't work just create a MyUtils class that has common methods you use.